# compare a subset of a list and return where it exists inside the list

Tags: python, list, intersection

I have two lists a and b, b is a small subset somewhere in a.

```
b = ['apple','banana','carrot']
a = list of length 100 which somewhere contains b at indices 12,13,14.
```

I would like to search for b in a and return the indices 12,13,14.

My current idea is to do two nested loops that look for the pattern but I was hoping there was a cleaner/easier solution.

Comment: yes, the basic approach is the 2 nested loops. For your problem it works well. You can also consider your lists as strings, and use any of those https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm (the KMP is usually very popular) (some of those algorithm may require the input to actually be strings, and therefore would not apply)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple possibility:

```
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a = ['t', 'z', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 't', 's', 'a', 'b']

[i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i:i+len(b)] == b]
```

Output: `[3]`

Returns the index of the first element of list `b` in list `a`. Notice that if `b` was repeated more than once inside `a`, this approach would return the two indexes for where `b` is repeated in `a`.

Comment: @nfnneil `12, 13, 14` in the case those are the correct indexes. Using this approach you get `3`, from which you can deduct the indexes will be `3, 4, 5`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  >>> a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
   >>> b=[4,5,6];
   >>> if b in a:
    print"found at:",a.index(b);
enter code here

found at: 1
```

//from python shell

Comment: This is not an answer because the OP has a flat list, not a list which has already been conveniently cut up.